# Replacement for deprecated juju sync-tools command in juju 2.0

Tags: juju

With JuJu's recent deprecation of the `juju sync-tools` command what is is the new way of caching  JuJu tools offline for offline use?

I should be able to bootstrap environments without an internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`juju sync-tools` is available in Juju 2.0 (it may not have been at the time the question was asked, however). Aside from a couple deprecated parameters, this should work the same as with Juju 1.x.

The commands documentation can be found here:
https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/commands